# как сделать так чтоб телеграм-бот не падал при длительном отсутствии обращений к нему

Tags: python, сервер, telegram-bot, telebot, google-cloud

Бот написан на python все работает нормально и так как нужно, но вот если к боту длительное время никто не обращался при первом обращении к нему он перезагружается. Понять в чем ошибка я не могу. В самом коде проблем нет... Скорее всего проблема в сервере. Использую GoogleCloudPlatform. Буду очень признателен если кто сможет подсказать в чем проблема, и как сделать так что б бот всегда был "на чеку" и ждал обращения пользователей?[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А логов нет? На самом сервере ограничений нет? Я просто запускал бота и в крон добавлял проверку на существование процесса. Если вдруг процесс упал (не отловил пару исключений), то он снова запускался.

Comment: Почему Вы считаете, что в коде проблем нет?

Comment: Запущенный бот на локально из консоли работал день для теста, никаких проблем при этом не наблюдалось. По этому сделал предварительный вывод что в коде нет ошибок. И даже на сервере при периодическом использовании бота он не падает. а вот если нет обращений длительное время то перезагружается. В принципе сам бот защищен от падений и перезапусков, данные не теряются при перезапуске, единственная проблема - в том что пользователь который "будит" бота ждет 5-6 сек чтоб он проснулся и вынужден несколько раз нажимать кнопку для начала работы, что отпугивает новых пользователей(

Comment: На сервере ничего не менял, только настроил файл bot.service (фото выше). В боте идет основной поток для создания заявок и дополнительный поток который периодически проверяет базу данных на наличие условий удовлетворяющих пользовательский запрос. Вышеописанная проблема возникает при создании новой заявки пользователем.

Answer (score 1):

если сервер который вы используете в GoogleCloudPlatform вне РФ, используйте [webhook](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI/blob/master/examples/webhook_examples/webhook_cherrypy_echo_bot.py), чтобы указать URL-адрес и получать входящие обновления через исходящий веб-крючок. Всякий раз, когда есть обновление для бота, мы будем отправлять HTTPS POST-запрос на указанный URL-адрес, содержащий JSON-сериализованное обновление . В случае неудачного запроса мы сдадимся после разумного количества попыток. Возвращает True в случае успеха.

сертификаты можно взять у [Certbot](https://certbot.eff.org/instructions)

Comment: Спасибо за идею, нужно подумать как реализовать...
Но преимущество все-таки работа без вебхуков!

Comment: getUpdates - pull: ваш бот постоянно дёргает сервер Telegram и проверяет есть ли новые сообщения;
setWebhook - push: по мере поступления новых сообщений сервер Telegram отправляет их вашему боту.

Comment: хм... извините за непонимание... 
Как можно в таком случае сделать ф-цию для обращения к базе дынных postgres с периодичностью в 1 мин? Если не сложно дайте фрагмент кода

Comment: я не вижу связи между коннектом к бд и переход от поллинга к хукам.
что хук что поллинг является связью вашего кода бота с серверами телеги, остальной код изменять не требуется

Comment: D. Violet спасибо большое Вам за ответ, буду читать и пробовать изменить работу бота!